# Python module 'json' has no attribute 'dumps error with python3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to run the below simple program

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, Docker!'
```

Flask is installed

```
pip3 install Flask
Requirement already satisfied: Flask in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.15 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Flask) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Flask) (7.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Flask) (2.11.2)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Flask) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10.1->Flask) (1.1.1)
```

The Json module that comes with Python3 is also there

```
pwd
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/json/schema

ls
__init__.py bases.py    draft04.py  exceptions.py   util.py
```

But when I grep for dumps in the json module under site-packages, it is not there.

I believe that is why when I run the script I am seeing the below error

```
python3 app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from jinja2 import escape
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .bccache import BytecodeCache
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/bccache.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .utils import open_if_exists
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/utils.py", line 41, in <module>
    _slash_escape = "\\/" not in json.dumps("/")
AttributeError: module 'json' has no attribute 'dumps'
```

I have been struggling with this for a while now and tried a lot of options but no luck.
Any suggestions will be helpful
Also, I understand that json module comes by default.

I am running this on MacOS BigSur

Comment: It is possible you have another module named `json`. try printing `json.__file__` to get its location

Comment: Did you name anything `json` ? A file, a variable ?

Comment: I think a folder at the root of your project can also cause this masking.